# while trying to use celery with django on ElasticBeantalk with Amazon -SQS and running, I am getting [Errno 13] Permission denied?

Tags: django, celery, amazon-sqs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to use celery with django. I have deployed my site on eleasticBeanStalk. I am also using AMAZON-SQS. On running the command

```
celery worker --app=prisons --loglevel == INFO
```

[prisons is the name of my django app & I have ran this command from eb ssh]

**I get the following error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: 'db'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 16, in main
    _main()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 322, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 496, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 298, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 488, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 420, in execute
    ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 223, in run_from_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 252, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 257, in run
    **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.setup_instance(**self.prepare_args(**kwargs))
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 141, in setup_instance
    self.blueprint.apply(self, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 214, in apply
    step.include(parent)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 343, in include
    return self._should_include(parent)[0]
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 339, in _should_include
    return True, self.create(parent)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/components.py", line 215, in create
    w._persistence = w.state.Persistent(w.state, w.statedb, w.app.clock)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/state.py", line 189, in __init__
    self.merge()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/state.py", line 197, in merge
    self._merge_with(self.db)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 44, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/state.py", line 266, in db
    return self.open()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/state.py", line 193, in open
    self.filename, protocol=self.protocol, writeback=True,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/shelve.py", line 243, in open
    return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/shelve.py", line 227, in __init__
    Shelf.__init__(self, dbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/dbm/__init__.py", line 94, in open
    return mod.open(file, flag, mode)
_gdbm.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

My project structure looks like this:

```
.elasticbeanstalk
.ebextenssions
----01_python.config
----02_python.config
----99_celery.config
home
prisons
----__init__.py
----celery.py
----urls.py
----wsgi.py
settings
----__init__.py
----default.py
----dev.py
----production.py
manage.py
```

**.ebextensions/01_python.config**

```
files:
  "/usr/local/share/pycurl-7.43.0.tar.gz" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    source: https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.43.0.tar.gz

packages:
  yum:
    python34-devel: []
    libcurl-devel: []
    git: []
    postgresql93-devel: []
    libjpeg-turbo-devel: []

commands:
  01_download_pip3:
    # run this before PIP installs requirements as it needs to be compiled with OpenSSL
    command: 'curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py'
  02_install_pip3:
    # run this before PIP installs requirements as it needs to be compiled with OpenSSL
    command: 'python3 get-pip.py'

container_commands:
  03_pycurl_reinstall:
    # run this before PIP installs requirements as it needs to be compiled with OpenSSL
    # the upgrade option is because it will run after PIP installs the requirements.txt file.
    # and it needs to be done with the virtual-env activated
    command: 'source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && pip3 install /usr/local/share/pycurl-7.43.0.tar.gz --global-option="--with-nss" --upgrade'
```

**.ebextensions/02_python.config**

```
container_commands:
    01_migrate:
        command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
        leader_only: true
    02_collect_static:
        command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```

**.ebextensions/99_celery.config**

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash

      # Create required directories
      sudo mkdir -p /var/log/celery/
      sudo mkdir -p /var/run/celery/

      # Create group called 'celery'
      sudo groupadd -f celery
      # add the user 'celery' if it doesn't exist and add it to the group with same name
      id -u celery &>/dev/null || sudo useradd -g celery celery
      # add permissions to the celery user for r+w to the folders just created
      sudo chown -R celery:celery /var/log/celery/
      sudo chown -R celery:celery /var/run/celery/

      # Get django environment variables
      celeryenv=`cat /opt/python/current/env | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/%/%%/g' | sed 's/export //g' | sed 's/$PATH/%(ENV_PATH)s/g' | sed 's/$PYTHONPATH//g' | sed 's/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH//g'`
      celeryenv=${celeryenv%?}

      # Create CELERY configuraiton script
      celeryconf="[program:celeryd]
      directory=/opt/python/current/app
      ; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
      command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery worker -A prisons --loglevel=INFO --logfile="/var/log/celery/%%n%%I.log" --pidfile="/var/run/celery/%%n.pid"

      user=celery
      numprocs=1
      stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
      stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
      autostart=true
      autorestart=true
      startsecs=10

      ; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
      ; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
      stopwaitsecs = 60

      ; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
      ; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
      ; taking care of its children as well.
      killasgroup=true

      ; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
      ; so it starts first
      priority=998

      environment=$celeryenv"


      # Create CELERY BEAT configuraiton script
      celerybeatconf="[program:celerybeat]
      ; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
      command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery beat –A prisons --loglevel=INFO --logfile="/var/log/celery/celery-beat.log" --pidfile="/var/run/celery/celery-beat.pid"

      directory=/opt/python/current/app
      user=celery
      numprocs=1
      stdout_logfile=/var/log/celerybeat.log
      stderr_logfile=/var/log/celerybeat.log
      autostart=true
      autorestart=true
      startsecs=10

      ; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
      ; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
      stopwaitsecs = 60

      ; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
      ; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
      ; taking care of its children as well.
      killasgroup=true

      ; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
      ; so it starts first
      priority=999

      environment=$celeryenv"

      # Create the celery supervisord conf script
      echo "$celeryconf" | tee /opt/python/etc/celery.conf
      echo "$celerybeatconf" | tee /opt/python/etc/celerybeat.conf

      # Add configuration script to supervisord conf (if not there already)
      if ! grep -Fxq "[include]" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
          then
          echo "[include]" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
          echo "files: celery.conf celerybeat.conf" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
      fi

      # Reread the supervisord config
      supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf reread

      # Update supervisord in cache without restarting all services
      supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf update

      # Start/Restart celeryd through supervisord
      supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celeryd
      supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celerybeat


commands:
  01_killotherbeats:
    command: "ps auxww | grep 'celery beat' | awk '{print $2}' | sudo xargs kill -9 || true"
    ignoreErrors: true
  02_restartbeat:
    command: "supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celerybeat"
    leader_only: true
```

**prisons/celery.py**

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
# DONE IN __init__.py
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.production")

app = Celery('prisons')

# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**prisons/__init__.py**

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.production")

# Add celery app defined in celery.py
__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

**settings/__init__.py**

```py
from .dev import *
```

**settings/default.py**

```py
"""
Django settings for prisons project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
ENV_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django_celery_beat',
    'home',
    'homePics',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'prisons.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'prisons.wsgi.application'

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ENV_PATH, "static")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ENV_PATH, 'media')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**settings/dev.py**

```py
from .default import *
DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

**settings/production.py**

```py
import os
from .default import *


DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['prisons-env.hhtwiv2cgj.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com']
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

INSTALLED_APPS += ['storages'] 

if 'RDS_HOSTNAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'prisons-static'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'


STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'prisons.storage_backends.MediaStorage'  # <-- here is where we reference it

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'sqs://'
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'sqs'


CELERY_BROKER_USER = os.environ['SQS_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
CELERY_BROKER_PASSWORD = os.environ['SQS_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
CELERY_WORKER_STATE_DB = '/var/run/celery/worker.db'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_WORKER_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 0         # See https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3712

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'celery'
CELERY_QUEUES = {
    CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE: {
        'exchange': CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE,
        'binding_key': CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE,
    }
}

CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'region': 'ap-south-1',
                                   'visibility_timeout': 3600,
                                   'polling_interval': 1,
                                   'queue_name_prefix': '%s-' % {True: 'dev',
                                                                 False: 'production'}[DEBUG],
                                   'CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER': 0,
                                   }

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
```

I still cannot get past the error. Can anyone help me on this?